# Php Globals v. Database calls for lots of data

Tags: php, database, performance, global-variables, database-performance

For large arrays, is it better to save the data to global variables or query the database each time I need them? In my situation keeping them local scope and passing them to functions isn't an option.

I'm using wordpress and in most pages I get every user and all metadata attached to them.  Often times I use these variables in multiple places on the same page.  Unfortunately wordpress won't let me pass variables between templates so I'm stuck either using global variables or calling the database each time.  Eventually, this will be hundreds of users with a lot of metadata attached to each.  Should I call the database each time to keep the variables local, or should save them to global variables to save on database queries?  What are the considerations? Should I worry about performance, overhead, and/or other issues?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Keeping the data in a global variable won't help much since you'll still have to reload it on every page view. Depending on your current architecture, using something like Redis for caching should make a big difference.

Comment: read http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real solution to your problem is using some kind of cache system ([Memcache](http://memcached.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/) are your best options). Fortunately, there are plenty of Wordpress plugins that make the integration an easy thing. For instance:

- Redis: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-object-cache/
- Memcache: https://wordpress.org/plugins/memcached/

**EDIT**

If you only want to cache a few databases calls, you can forget about Wordpress plugins and start coding a bit. Let's say you only want to cache the call for retrieving the list of users from database, and let's assume you are using Memcache to accomplish this task (Memcache stores key-value pairs and allows super fast access to a value given a key).

1. Query Memcache asking for the key "*users*".
2. Memcache still doesn't have such key, so you'll have a cache fail and after it, you'll  query your database to retrieve the user list. Now serialize the database response ([serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) are two different ways to do this) and store the key "*users*" along this serialized value in your memcache.
3. Next time you query your memcache asking for "users", you'll get a hit. In this moment you just have to unserialize the value and work with your user list.

And that's all. Now you just have to decide what you want to cache and apply this procedure to those elements.

Comment: Is there a good way to cache the database call only on that single page load? And/or cache 90% of the information while still updating the 10% that will change regularly, almost every page view?

Comment: @DavidHobs I have edited my answer and added a procedure which shows how to cache only what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to perform the calls but once per page, you might have to execute the call once for every page. So I would suggest you creating some sort of class to interact with your database that you can call on to get the data that you need. I would also recommend using stored procedures and functions on your database instead of straight queries since this will help both with security and separation of application logic and data functionality.

Comment: Why suggest stored procedures or functions here without even understanding the query access pattern? What you suggest actually does the opposite of what you say it does.  You would potentially be moving application data access logic out of the application and into the database with such an approach. Also, I don't know what using stored procedures and functions has to do with security.

Comment: Okay my understand might be off so I am gonna try to explain myself and maybe you can correct me where I am miss understand how this all works. With a stored procedure or function you would perform some sort of select statement and possibly return the data that was pulled from the database. Then you would perform the logic on that data in the PHP. Isn't this how it is supposed to be done or is my understanding way off. As for security again if I remember correctly when using a stored procedure the driver is supposed to automatically sanitize the parameter when it is passed in.

Comment: From a security standpoint, more common practice would be to use prepared statements where the query execution plan is determined separately from the parametric data that is passed in, meaning potentially harmful data (SQL injection) cannot actually effect query behavior. Using a stored procedure to, in essence, wrap a SELECT statement would probably be overkill and would potentially hide the intent of the query from the application programmer. I would think of stored procedures or functions more for cases where you are in essence trying to expand base MySQL functionality.

Comment: Okay, from the way this reads it sounds like there are certain times it is best to use a stored package over not. Through my course work at my college and on the job that is all we ever use and no one ever questions it. Is there a certain time you would won't to use one over the other? I have only been out of college for about a year and I am still trying to learn.

Comment: Honestly, different shops may take different approaches.  If you have a strong DBA team, perhaps a company may tend to put more logic into stored procedures/functions (not necessarily because of any actual design consideration).  I personally like to keep application logic in the application layer, and persistence logic in the persistence layer.  I could see however if you have a number of applications interacting with a common DB, and you need some common DB behaviors/functionalities to be exposed, that perhaps this might make more sense to write stored procedures to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking some time to help clear some of this up and that does make more sense.